# How to pass an absolute url in django

Tags: python, django

How would I pass an absolute url to a django function and redirect to it?

```
def function(request):
    back_url = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']    # example.com/home/?status=80&page=1
    return redirect(back_url)
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question or elaborate a bit more? `redirect` can take full URLs, maybe I don't get your point...

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo -- I see, looks like what I posted above will work. Though I'll keep the question, as I think the answer below accounts for the full url redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
def func(request):
    url  = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
    if request.META['QUERY_STRING']:
        url += '?%s' % request.META['QUERY_STRING']
    return redirect_to(request, url, **kwargs)
```